# Brightscript - Limit on number of functions

Tags: roku, brightscript

Plexinc states in his roku-client-public repository:

"The Roku BrightScript compiler enforces a limit on the number of functions that can be defined by an app. This is particularly evil because the limit is different for the 3.x and 4.x firmware--512 and 768 respectively"

https://github.com/plexinc/roku-client-public

I can't find this documented anywhere but Plexinc's repo. Is there further documentation to back this up? Is there a limit for the 5.x firmware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered on the Roku Forum:

http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=56875

"The limit was raised to 65,536 in 4.10 (UK) and 5.x. It will be similarly raised for the legacy 3.x firmware in an upcoming release."